# override properties file from dependency with the one in resources

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I've a log4j.properties in src/main/resources and there are dependencies that also contain log4j.properties.
When I build my project using maven assembly plugin sometimes log4j.properties is picked from resources and sometime from dependencies.
I want it to be picked everytime from resources.

Comment: Can you show your full pom file and your assembly descriptors.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of excluding log4j.properties files, you can also rename your file  and add a system property that points to it. For example: you can rename your file to "my-log4j.properties" and then add the following to your execution line: `java ... -Dlog4j.configuration=my-log4j.properties ...`